# How to display 4 items in one view when scrolling in Jinja2

Tags: jinja2

I am trying to implement this program into my raspberry pi magic mirror. Here is the repository that I found in GitHub:
https://github.com/jalibu/MMM-Jast/tree/main

Everything is working as expected but there is an issue to display stocks. So it is displaying one stock and then scroll but what I want, to show 4 stocks and then scroll.

I believe this part of code needs to be changed but I couldn't figure out how:

```
{% macro render(num="1") %}
  <p class="jast-hticker jast-ticker-no{{ num }}">
    <span class="jast-tickerframe">
    {% for i in range(0, config.virtualHorizontalMultiplier) -%}
    {% for stock in stocks %}
        {% if not stock.meta.hidden or config.showHiddenStocks %}
          <span class="jast-stock">{{ utils.getStockName(stock) }}:
            {% if utils.getStockChange(stock) > 0 %}
              {% set colorClass = "high" %}
            {% elif utils.getStockChange(stock) < 0 %}
              {% set colorClass = "low" %}
            {% else %}
              {% set colorClass = "" %}
            {% endif %}
            <span class="{{ colorClass }}">
              {{ utils.getCurrentValueAsString(stock, config) }}
              {% if colorClass and (config.showChangeValue or config.showChangePercent) %}
                <span class="jast-change">
                  ({% if config.showChangeValue %}<span class="jast-change-value">{% if colorClass == "high" %}+{%endif%}{{ utils.getStockChangeAsString(stock, config) }}</span>{% endif %}
                  {% if config.showChangePercent %}<span class="jast-change-value">{% if colorClass == "high" %}+{%endif%}{{ utils.getStockChangePercentAsString(stock, config) }}</span>{% endif %})
                </span>
              {% endif %}
            </span>
          </span>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if config.showPortfolioValue or config.showPortfolioGrowth or config.showPortfolioGrowthPercent%}
      {% set portfolio = utils.getPortfolio(stocks, config) %}
        <span class="jast-stock">{{ "portfolio" | translate | safe }}
          {% for entry in portfolio %}
            {% if entry.value > entry.oldValue %}
              {% set colorClass = "high" %}
            {% elif entry.value < entry.oldValue %}
              {% set colorClass = "low" %}
            {% else %}
              {% set colorClass = "" %}
            {% endif %}
            <span class="{{ colorClass }}{% if loop.index != 1 %} jast-multi-currency{% endif %}">
              {% if config.showPortfolioValue %} {{ utils.getPortfolioValueAsString(entry, config) }} {% endif %}
              {% if colorClass and (config.showPortfolioGrowth or config.showPortfolioGrowthPercent) %}
                {% if config.showPortfolioValue %}<span class="jast-change">({% endif %}
                {% if config.showPortfolioGrowth %}<span class="jast-change-value">{% if colorClass == "high" %}+{%endif%}{{ utils.getPortfolioChangeAsString(entry, config) }}</span>{% endif %}
                {% if config.showPortfolioGrowthPercent %}<span class="jast-change-value">{% if colorClass == "high" %}+{%endif%}{{ utils.getPortfolioChangePercentAsString(entry, config) }}</span>{% endif %}
                {% if config.showPortfolioValue %})</span>{% endif %}
              {% endif %}
            </span>
          {% endfor %}
        </span>
      {% endif %}
      {% if config.showLastUpdate %}
        <span class="jast-stock">{{ "lastUpdate" | translate | safe }} {{ lastUpdate }}</span>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </span>
  </p>
{% endmacro %}
```